# News API in django python?

Tags: python, django, api

*Iam Using a newsapi key in my website, when I try to access only one news I having trouble?
How can I access Only one Particular news in my page? (not whole news using loop)*

**views.py**

```
API_KEY = '1099d3305d5c43f0ba9706b17dd1fe1c'
def sports(request):
    url = f'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?language=en&category=sports&apiKey={API_KEY}'
    url2 = f'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?language=en&apiKey={API_KEY}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    response2 = requests.get(url2)
    data = response.json()
    data2 = response2.json()
    articles = data['articles']
    articles2 = data2['articles']
    context = {
        'articles' : articles,
        'articles2' : articles2
    }
    return render(request, 'app/sports.html', context)
```

Comment: share JSON response

Comment: Your real API key?

Comment: no, this is api key from another website